# Loop through all cells in a column and copy and paste text if match is found

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, copy-paste, with-statement

I am struggling with a simple task. This code currently works:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set criteriarange = Range("A1:A" & LShtRow)
        For Each criteriacell In criteriarange
            If Not criteriacell.Value Like "tag:*" Then
                criteriacell.ClearContents
            End If
        Next criteriacell
        For row = LShtRow To 1 Step -1
            With .Cells(row, "B")
                If IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ArrDataNames, 0)) Then .ClearContents
            End With
        Next row
End With
```

I need to loop through these same cells and look for what I am calling "exceptions." I am putting these exceptions in an array. Currently the array only has one exception and it is "FM" and if it finds "FM" in column "B" row i then I want to copy the text from column "E" row i and paste it to column "H" row i. Here is what I have been trying but it is saying "type mismatch." I am sure it is some simple syntax but i have tried a few things and can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
Dim ArrExceptions As Variant
ArrExceptions = Array("FM")

With ActiveSheet
    Set criteriarange = Range("A1:A" & LShtRow)
        For Each criteriacell In criteriarange
            If Not criteriacell.Value Like "tag:*" Then
                criteriacell.ClearContents
            End If
        Next criteriacell
        For row = LShtRow To 1 Step -1
            With .Cells(row, "B")
                If IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ArrDataNames, 0)) Then .ClearContents
            End With
        Next row
'New Code'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        For row = LShtRow To 1 Step -1
                If Application.Match(.Cells(row, "B").Value, ArrExceptions, 0) Then .Range(.Cells(row, "E")).Copy .Range(.Cells(row, "H"))
        Next row
End With
```

Comment: Try wrapping your new line with `If Not IsError()`, like: `If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(row, "B").Value, ArrExceptions, 0)) Then`

Comment: Ok... that solved the error I was having... That makes since in hind sight... Anyways now have a new error... Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error... I was able to do a debug.print row and step through the loop and the loop starts a row 207 and goes to row 17 where is errors (this is the first row with "FM")

Comment: So... What I am saying is... It looks like the problem is in the: .Range(.Cells(row, "E")).Copy .Range(.Cells(row, "H"))

Comment: Got it... Should have been: .Cells(row, "E").Copy .Cells(row, "H")

Comment: Sorry! I just logged back in. I'm glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set criteriarange = Range("A1:A" & LShtRow)
        For Each criteriacell In criteriarange
            If Not criteriacell.Value Like "tag:*" Then
                criteriacell.ClearContents
            End If
        Next criteriacell
        For row = LShtRow To 1 Step -1
            With .Cells(row, "B")
                If IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ArrDataNames, 0)) Then .ClearContents
            End With
        Next row
        For row = LShtRow To 1 Step -1
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(row, "B").Value, ArrExceptions, 0)) Then .Cells(row, "E").Copy .Cells(row, "H")
        Next row
End With
```